# Count the cells in col A that have entries in col B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, countif, vba

I am working on a table with thousands of entries. I am looking for a formula that will count all the records in the column A that have data in column B.

Some cells from column A could be merged and being represented by 2 entries in column B which are 2 cells. It is like one cell in column A have 2 cells in column B, being altogether one line. I hope I made myself understandable.

I tried to use like countif, but it's not the case I guess...

I have attached a  little example in the below link.

[image]

Hope there is someone that could help me with that.

Comment: why don't you count cells which are not null in column B? I would prefer to lose all merged cells. (Set both A1 and A2 as PC1 in your case) and use pivot table for grouping. In that way you can do any count operation easily.

Comment: Merged cells are tricky to work with, and can cause hard to find problems in the future.  But, for your layout, the following should work: `=COUNTA(A1:A5)-COUNTBLANK(B1:B5)`.  Of course, if you have a merged cell in Column A which has only a single entry in column B, the count will be wrong.  It would be best if you could devise a different layout, that does not involve merged cells.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I understand. Unfortunately, the way how it merged it does not depend on me, I am exporting data from a website and I have only to manipulate them...and there are thousands..

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I just got smth on my mind. Is it possible to (un)merged those merged cells? Instead of one single PC1 to have two of PC1 for each entry of col B?

Comment: @bnktop You can do it with VBA.

Comment: @ctumturk, that is actually good idea. how do I do that fast for thousand entries?

Comment: First insert a new column between Column A and B. Than use a formula like `=IF(A4="";A3;A4)` in that new column. Just be careful with the first cell which is B1. With this you can get rid of merged cells. It is actually more practical than it sounds:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5<>"")*--(B1:B5<>""))
```

The above counts the number of rows where A is not blank and B is not blank

Comment: 2 points:  **1**.  Since you are multiplying within `SUMPRODUCT`, the double unary is not required.  **2**.  If `A1:A2` are merged, with `B1` blank and data in `B2`, a match will NOT be counted.